# What does the parameter 'args=(not_set = true)' mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found a method definition in the [github API v3](https://github.com/peter-murach/github/blob/master/lib/github_api/api.rb#L91), I don't know the meaning of the `args=(not_set = true)`.

Can you show me some examples of the usage? thanks.

```
# Acts as setter and getter for api requests arguments parsing.
#
# Returns Arguments instance.
#
def arguments(args=(not_set = true), options={}, &block)
  if not_set
    @arguments
  else
    @arguments = Arguments.new(self, options).parse(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `args` setter method will only be triggered if you pass no data.

If you do:

```
arguments("foo")
```

Then:

- `args #=> "foo"`
- `not_set #=> nil` which is falsy

If you do:

```
arguments()
```

Then:

- `args #=> nil`
- `not_set #=> true`

To be short: it's a pretty neat way to check if one arg has really been set.

Comment: Did not understand what is called these technique in *Ruby*?

Answer (score 4):

The interesting question is not how the code works: if `args` is not passed, the code `not_set = true` will be evaluated.

Rather, the important question is **why would someone go to this trouble**? After all, the much simpler alternative usually works just fine:

```
def arguments(args = nil)
  if args.nil?
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

However, that approach does not allow you to distinguish these two calls:

```
arguments()
arguments(nil)
```

If that distinction matters, you could use an approach like the one in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

As per this [blog](http://www.mobalean.com/blog/2009/02/28/hacking-rubys-default-arguments), default value for a parameter can be result of an executed expression.  So, what they are doing is setting a flag in an expression (not_set=true) and using that as default value.  So, in cases where "args" is not specified, the expression (not_set=true) will get evaluated.

Read the [link for really interesting examples](http://www.mobalean.com/blog/2009/02/28/hacking-rubys-default-arguments).